# How to export data from neo4j to a MySQL table

Tags: neo4j

I have below data in my neo4j database which I want to insert into mysql table using jdbc.

```
"{""id"":7512,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""Nishant"",""group_uuid"":""6b27c9c8-4d5b-4ebc-b8c2-667bb159e029""}}"
"{""id"":7513,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""anish"",""group_uuid"":""6b27c9c8-4d5b-4ebc-b8c2-667bb159e029""}}"
"{""id"":7519,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""nishant"",""group_uuid"":""6b27c9c8-4d5b-4ebc-b8c2-667bb159e029""}}"
"{""id"":7520,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""xiaoyi"",""group_uuid"":""9d7d4bf6-6db6-4cf2-8186-d8d0621a58c5""}}"
"{""id"":7521,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""pavan"",""group_uuid"":""3ddc954a-16f5-4c59-a94a-b262f9784211""}}"
"{""id"":7522,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""jose"",""group_uuid"":""6b27c9c8-4d5b-4ebc-b8c2-667bb159e029""}}"
"{""id"":7523,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""neil"",""group_uuid"":""9d7d4bf6-6db6-4cf2-8186-d8d0621a58c5""}}"
"{""id"":7524,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""menish"",""group_uuid"":""9d7d4bf6-6db6-4cf2-8186-d8d0621a58c5""}}"
"{""id"":7525,""labels"":[""person1""],""properties"":{""person1"":""ankur"",""group_uuid"":""3ddc954a-16f5-4c59-a94a-b262f9784211""}}"
```

Desired Output in mysql database table.

```
id,name,group_id
7525,ankur,3ddc954a-16f5-4c59-a94a-b262f9784211
7524,menish,9d7d4bf6-6db6-4cf2-8186-d8d0621a58c5
...
```

Comment: What is your neo4j data model?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide much info in your question, here is a general approach for exporting from neo4j to MySQL.

1. Execute a Cypher query using one of the APOC [export to CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/export/csv/#export-csv) procedures to export the data intended for the table to a CSV file.
2. Import from the CSV file into MySQL. (E.g., [here is a tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/).)

Comment: Many thanks for the solution, I just want to know any direct option to load data from neo4j to mysql database(without using csv).